# Возникновение непонятного числа при записи в файл

Tags: c++, файлы, структуры

Имеется часть кода:

```
struct orders {
    string product;
    string mark;
    string surname;
    string name;
    string secondName;
    string phoneNumber;
    int cost;
    int dayOfRecept;
    int monthOfRecept;
    int yearOfRecept;
    int dayOfIssue;
    int monthOfIssue;
    int yearOfIssue;
    bool status;
};
void addOrder(orders Orders) {
    ofstream file("order.txt", ios_base::app);
    cout << "Enter the product" << endl;
    cin >> Orders.product;
    cout << "Enter the mark" << endl;
    cin >> Orders.mark;
    cout << "Enter the surname" << endl;
    cin >> Orders.surname;
    cout << "Enter the name" << endl;
    cin >> Orders.name;
    cout << "Enter the second name" << endl;
    cin >> Orders.secondName;
    cout << "Enter the phone number" << endl;
    cin >> Orders.phoneNumber;
    cout << "Enter the cost" << endl;
    cin >> Orders.cost;
    cout << "Enter the day of recept" << endl;
    cin >> Orders.dayOfRecept;
    cout << "Enter the month of recept" << endl;
    cin >> Orders.monthOfRecept;
    cout << "Enter the year of recept" << endl;
    cin >> Orders.yearOfRecept;
    cout << "Enter the day of issue" << endl;
    cin >> Orders.dayOfIssue;
    cout << "Enter the month of issue" << endl;
    cin >> Orders.monthOfIssue;
    cout << "Enter the year of issue" << endl;
    cin >> Orders.yearOfIssue;
    file << Orders.product << " " << Orders.mark << " " << Orders.surname << " " << Orders.name << " " << Orders.secondName << " " << Orders.phoneNumber << " " <<
        Orders.cost << " " << Orders.dayOfRecept << " " << Orders.monthOfRecept << " " << Orders.yearOfRecept << " " << Orders.dayOfIssue << " " << Orders.monthOfIssue
        << " " << Orders.yearOfIssue << " " << Orders.status <<"\n";
    file.close();
    cout << "Order added!" << endl;
}
```

Задача - считывание данных с консоли и запись их в файл. Однако после записи, открывая файл, при любом вводе в конце обнаруживаю непонятно откуда взявшееся число 204. Выглядит это так:

```
1 b c d e f 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 204
```

В чем ошибка?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Поле `orders::status` явно остается неинициализированным.